# Copying data from one column to another table in a separate database on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, data-transfer

I am trying to figure out how to copy the data in one column back over to another table on the same server but in a separate database.

This will be done after performing an Entity Framework migration. I have tested it pretty thoroughly and know it will update the database schema correctly, but because of various reasons there is a column that will lose all of its data.

I have the original database (pre-EF migration) backed up and have created a duplicate database on the same server that I have restored that `.bak` file to.

What I am now trying to do is copy all of the data from the column in the backed up table (that gets cleared in the migration) back over to the post-migration table.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
UPDATE [PostMigDB].dbo.Issues 
SET Branch = [PreMigDB].dbo.IssueBranches.Branch
WHERE [PostMigDB].dbo.Issues.Id = [PreMigDB].dbo.IssueBranches.IssueId
```

But in the Query Editor, both expressions starting with `[PreMigDB]` are underlined in red and when I hover my mouse over them it reads:

> The multi-part identifier [PreMigDB].dbo...  could not be bound

Almost everything I have read online says this should be possible, but I cannot figure out why it won't work for me. Thank you all.

Comment: You can't automagically reference another table, you have to join it on. And you will also find that using aliases makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: Also you don't need 3/4 part naming since your tables are all in the same database.

Comment: Well, they are on the same server, but separate databases. I created a new database on the same server and restored the .bak file to this new database. Should this still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your [join logic](https://datatofish.com/join-tables-different-databases-sql-server/).

```
UPDATE i
SET Branch = b.Branch
FROM [PostMigDB].dbo.Issues i
INNER JOIN [PreMigDB].dbo.IssueBranches b ON b.IssueId = i.Id
```

Comment: Or in fact actually some join logic :) However once you alias a table you should then reference the alias e.g. `update i  set Branch = b.Branch ...`

Comment: Halfway, you really should `UPDATE i` i.e. update the alias - not the table name.

Comment: Also you don't need 3/4 part naming since the tables are all in the same database.

Comment: This was very helpful and I was able to solve my issue. Thank you!